# Select by name in laravel 5.6 api

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

I have in my database many ads , I want to select one from theme by name I try but I get a null return

```
 public function index()
    {
        # code...
       // $Ads = ads::all();
     //  return $this->sendResponse($Ads->toArray(), 'Ads read succesfully');
        $column = 'name'; // This is the name of the column you wish to search

        $Ads = ads::where($column)->first();

        return response()->json(['success'=> true,'ads'=>$Ads, 'message'=> 'Ads read succesfully']);
    }
```

and this what I get in post man:

> {
>       "success": true,
>       "ads": null,
>       "message": "Ads read succesfully" }

Comment: Where is `$id` assigned?

Comment: this is a solution I found it in stackoverflow

Comment: I already fix this falut

Comment: You can't always just copy/paste code you've found without understanding it. `$id` is not created anywhere, so you're passing in a null value. Your code now just says `where $column` which means you're not actually checking against anything. The proper format would be `ads::where('name', '=', $name)->first()` where `$name` contains some value. You'll need to either hard-code the variable, or get it from the request somehow.

Comment: yes I know , I say I already fix it thank's , but how I can do it?

Comment: I unterstand thank's a lot man :D i fix it now thank's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some things to note before you dig in:

1. You need to have Request variable so that you can fetch the user input or if its static then just provide it static. However, static doesnt make sense so I am providing a code that will take input variable.
2. You need to compare the value with column name in order to fetch it.
3. Name of the models should be singular form and start with capital as its same as class name so you should use Ad instead of ads, ads is proper for table name, not for model name.

Considering above notes, here is the code which will work for you:

```
public function index(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request)
        {
            # code...
            $column = 'name'; // This is the name of the column you wish to search
            $columnValue = $request->input('name');// This is the value of the column you wish to search
            $Ads = Ad::where($column, $columnValue)->first();

            return response()->json(['success'=> true,'ads'=>$Ads, 'message'=> 'Ads read succesfully']);
        }
```